# Custom validators on Wagtail fields

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I have a `TextField` I would like to add a `min_length` to.

According to the Django docs there are built in validators you can use to enforce this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator).

I tried to add this to my model with this code:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    ...
    introduction = models.TextField(
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(240, message="Must be at least 240 chars.")]
```

When publishing this page with a value lower than 240, however, I did not get the expected validation error, but instead hit a `TypeError`: `unorderable types: str() < int()`.

Is there a way to have a `min_length` on a `TextField`?

Comment: how about `validators=MinLengthValidator(240)` _without a `message`_?

Comment: I received the same error.

Comment: with parameter: `min_length=240`

Comment: I have tried that as well and got an error "unexpected argument".

Comment: did you tried to create cutom validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If default `MinLengthValidator` isn't work for you, I suggest you to crate a custom validator like below:

```
from django.core.validators import ValidationError

def max_length_validator(value):
    if len(value) < 240:
        raise ValidationError("Must be at least 240 chars.")


class MyPage(Page):
    introduction = models.TextField(
        blank=False, validators=[max_length_validator])
```

Comment: I was using the wrong validator `MinValueValidator`. `MinLengthValidator` worked just fine. Thanks for your help